# Keybinding in Java not working

Tags: java

This is issue is probably very small but the frustrates the hell out of me. I've been trying to make a small program to get my head around keybinds, but its giving errors.

```
    public static void key() {
    //another way to use the JComonent class?
    JComponent component;
    Main main = new Main();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(main);

    Action test = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    };
    //"The local variable component may not have been initialized" for component
    component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "test");
    component.getActionMap().put("test", test);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to share what errors you get, or nah?

Comment: @Kon The error is as a comment in the code.

Comment: A key binding MUST be assigned to a component which is attached to a displayable container.  Unless the component is displayed on the screen, it will never receive key events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign a value to `JComponent component;` Thats why you get the error.

You can change it to `JComponent component = null;` and the error is gone. But you get a NPE in the line `component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "test");` at runtime, so you have to assign a proper value to `component.

Comment: Yeah i tried doing null, and as you said the NPE occurred. but what values do I assign to component? Thanks for the response

Comment: It depends n what you what to do.  Use `component = frame.getRootPane()`

Comment: hmm... frame.getRootPane() doesn't give any errors, but when I press "A", nothing happens, ActionPreformed isnt getting called. What I am trying to do, is to get keypresses to output text in the console when focused on the main frame.